# Printing nested lists of a list on different lines

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have the following list:

```
l = [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6]]
```

I can get the following result:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5]
[6]
```

by using this code:

```
for n in l:
    print n
```

How can I get the following results which are not list:

```
1, 2, 3
4, 5
6
```

I am trying this:

```
for n in l:
    for s in n:
        print s
```

but it gives this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With:

```
for n in l:
    for s in n:
        print s,
    print
```

You will get:

```
1 2 3
4 5
6
```

Comment: This is what i needed. what i can understand is that the ',' get everything on the same line. but what does the second print do?

Comment: @Coddy It just print `'\n'` to move to a new line.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> l = [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6]]
>>> for ns in l:
...     print ', '.join(map(str, ns))
...
1, 2, 3
4, 5
6
>>> for ns in l:
...     print str(ns)[1:-1]
...
1, 2, 3
4, 5
6
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> print '\n'.join(str(n).strip('[]') for n in l)
1, 2, 3
4, 5
6
```